# Why is my HTTP response not showing up in my browser?

Tags: java, http

I am trying to write an HTTP server in Java. After going through examples and adding in some stuff for debugging, this is what I have so far:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class AddyServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    try{
        System.err.println("Trying...");
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        System.err.println("Waiting...");
        //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            while(true) {
                System.err.println("Waiting...");
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                System.err.println("accepted");

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());



                String line;
                while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
                        if(line.isEmpty())
                            break;
                        out.print(line+"\r\n");
                        System.out.print(line+"\r\n");
                }

                out.print("HTTP/1.1 200\r\n"); //EDITED
                out.print("Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
                out.print("Connection: close\r\n");
                out.print("\r\n");
                out.print("<!doctype html>\n");
                out.print("<title>Test title</title>\n");
                out.print("<p>Test</p>\n");

                System.out.print("HTTP/1.1 200 \r\n");
                System.out.print("Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
                System.out.print("Connection: close\r\n");
                System.out.print("\r\n");
                System.out.print("<!doctype html>\n");
                System.out.print("<title>Test title</title>\n");
                System.out.print("<p>Test</p>\n");

                in.close();
                out.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {System.err.println(e);} //EDITED
    }
}
```

I do not understand why my internet browser is not displaying the HTTP response body in the browser when I try connecting to my server.

Comment: You are squashing exceptions

Comment: I'm not sure but I would try to remove the space behind the 200.

Comment: @StephenC I know that I am not handling exceptions in an ideal way. I just added a println statement to print out any exception e that might be thrown. The server console is outputting the System.out.println statements but, the browser is not showing anything.

Comment: @rekire I tried getting rid of the space just now. No luck.

Comment: If that flush idea doesn't work try adding a content length, however I think that is optional. I would need to read the RFC to check that.

Comment: The space shouldn't be a problem

Comment: The browser is saying "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading." Maybe I need to somehow delay clientSocket closing? I am going to see if I can find some way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output isn't getting flushed (actually sent). Use `flush()` on the `PrintWriter` and it should work.

A [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) doesn't necessarily flush automatically.
My guess is that you close the socket (hence interrupting the connection) before the `PrintWriter` has been able to flush upon closing.

As an alternative to flushing right before closing (**recommended**), you could construct your PrintWriter with automatic line flushing (not recommended) as

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
```

In which case calls to `printf`, `println` or `format` will flush it (but not calls to `print`).

Comment: Does a close() not enfoce a flush()?

Comment: I tried adding a flush, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @alphagamma The close should flush any outstanding data, but you want to explicitly flush after writing to it so that http connection doesn't reset because the client hasn't received anything.

Comment: It was the flushing issue apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Add a flush after writing to socket (via PrintWriter). Also you need to close the serverSocket at some point, otherwise, you'll have issues just testing it with port being already bound.

**edit** This shows exactly where you want to flush. Tested and works for me.

Working fixed code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class AddyServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        System.err.println("Trying...");
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        System.err.println("Waiting...");
        // PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),
        // true);
        while (true) {
            System.err.println("Waiting...");
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            System.err.println("accepted");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.isEmpty())
                    break;
                out.print(line + "\r\n");
                System.out.print(line + "\r\n");
            }

            out.print("HTTP/1.1 200 \r\n");
            out.print("Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
            out.print("Connection: close\r\n");
            out.print("\r\n");
            out.print("<!doctype html>\n");
            out.print("<title>Test title</title>\n");
            out.print("<p>Test</p>\n");
            out.flush();  // <--- Fix is here

            System.out.print("HTTP/1.1 200 \r\n");
            System.out.print("Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
            System.out.print("Connection: close\r\n");
            System.out.print("\r\n");
            System.out.print("<!doctype html>\n");
            System.out.print("<title>Test title</title>\n");
            System.out.print("<p>Test</p>\n");

            in.close();
            out.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It was the flush. I guess the out.print wasn't "flushing the PrintWriter", or something like that. I don't know if that makes sense the way I worded it.